# Regex Not printing string between parenthesis in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have researched this up and down am can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have the following variable which I get from $_GET.

```
$monitorname = $_GET['monitorname'];
```

which should look something similar to: `985_Sands-Road(54dd14d80bd5f777184cb9c8)`, in the URL it actually looks like:

```
index.php?monitorname=985_Sands-Road%26%2340%3B54dd14d80bd5f777184cb9c8%26%2341%3B&alertType=0"
```

I'm trying to use Regex to get the text between the parentheses, here is my regex code:

```
preg_match('/\(([^)]+)\)/', $monitorname, $match);
$id = $match[1];
echo $id;
```

However no matter what I do, it won't echo the ID. What can I look at and fix in this? It must be noted that when I save the string explicitly as a variable it works fine:

```
$text = '985_Sands-Road(54dd14d80bd5f777184cb9c8)';
preg_match('/\(([^)]+)\)/', $text, $match);
$id = $match[1];
echo $id;
```

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Did you try using `preg_match('/%26%2340%3B(.*?)%26%2341%3B/', $text, $match);` ? I think these are something like `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks for your comment. I just tried it and still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$monitorname = $_GET['monitorname'];
$src=array('&#40;','&#41;');
$rep=array('(',')');
$monitorname=str_replace($src,$rep,$monitorname);

//now your code

preg_match('/\(([^)]+)\)/', $monitorname, $match);
$id = $match[1];
echo $id;
```

My first thought was urldecode() too, but it doesn't work in this case...

Comment: OMG That's Awesome... it worked. You can't imagine how long I've spent trying to figure this out. I wanna give you a big hug right now!! Thank you so much.

Comment: Np, glad to help, echo $monitorname; was helpful. :)

Comment: And, right now, as i can see - Jefersonfs found better solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

Look, the GET data is URL ENCODED.
You need use `string urldecode ( string $str )` to decode and `string html_entity_decode ( string $string [, int $quote_style [, string $charset ]] )`.

```
`html_entity_decode(urldecode("985_Sands-Road%26%2340%3B54dd14d80bd5f777184cb9c8%26%2341%3B"));`
```

Like : 
    `$monitorname = $_GET["monitorname"];
     $monitorname = html_entity_decode(urldecode($monitorname));
     //CODE
     preg_match('/\(([^)]+)\)/', $monitorname, $match);
     $id = $match[1];
     echo $id;`

More information in : 
[PHP MANUAL - URLDECODE](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urldecode.php) 
[PHP MANUAL - HTML_ENTITY_DECODE](http://php.net/html_entity_decode)

Updated!

Comment: I meant to add this to the notes, I've tried decoding and then echoing the results and it just comes out blank. When I encode I made sure to echo it encoded and I can see it, just the regex won't work. I'm completely baffled by this.